# Sync a OneDrive (or Dropbox / Google Drive) folder between multiple users

Tags: sync, dropbox, onedrive, google-drive

In OneDrive, I have shared a folder that has a few hundred files and subfolders for a project. It contains a lot of large zip files (in total, about 8 GB of files) so would not be suitable for GitHub. I would like a colleague to be able to download only those items that have changed to his local copy, similar to what a `robocopy /mir` or a github repository would do.

If this is not possible with OneDrive, but is possible with Dropbox or Google Drive that would also be fine. i.e. I would like a way to sync (changes only) between multiple users, using a freely available cloud solution.

If possible, a command line option to achieve this would be preferable, but for example, if a 3rd party tool like FileZilla (as an example, could be anything) can connect to the cloud and facilitate the sync, that would also be a good option.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing your point, but what you want is exactly how cloud sync services work. Of course this assumes that your colleagues have their own OneDrive (or whatever else) account. The only issue is that for 8GB there are not a lot of free services: OneDrive is limited to 5GB, Dropbox to 2GB... Google Drive can handle 15GB for free, so this would do. Do not forget however that the 8GB will be counted in the quota of each of your colleagues who accept the share.

Comment: Ah, my bad, you are right, I've been sharing by giving him a link to share it, and he downloads ad hoc, but I remember seeing this in Dropbox but never set it up, I think this is what I need then, thanks. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-and-sync-shared-folders-to-onedrive-for-home-8a63cd47-1526-4cd8-bd09-ee3f9bfc1504

Answer (score 0):

OneDrive for Business Mirrors by default. If you share a file and provide edit rights, all edits will be replicated in real time (even providing a contact icon or initials on active cursor interactions).

What you're actually doing when sharing a OneDrive file is sharing a link with access rights to that individual, or to all with the link (You can choose). Providing access to the OneDrive location makes governance easier rather than creating multiple copies of the file or folder.

Additionally:
To protect against changes when sharing a file or directory you should should select "people you specify can edit" at the bottom which will then present a link to copy and the option "Can edit" as well as "block download" to prevent read-only users making their own, non-vetted copies that inevitably end up in distribution.